# Twitter Ruby Gem can't authenticate

Tags: ruby, twitter

I keep getting the error below even though I've double checked all my tokens.

This is the full error:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/twitter-5.1.1/lib/twitter/rest/response/raise_error.rb:22:in `on_complete': Could not authenticate you (Twitter::Error::Unauthorized)
from /Users/gregg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/faraday-0.8.8/lib/faraday/response.rb:9:in `block in call'
from /Users/gregg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/faraday-0.8.8/lib/faraday/response.rb:63:in `on_complete'
from /Users/gregg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/faraday-0.8.8/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
from /Users/gregg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/faraday-0.8.8/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:14:in `call'
from /Users/gregg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/faraday-0.8.8/lib/faraday/request/multipart.rb:13:in `call'
from /Users/gregg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/twitter-5.1.1/lib/twitter/rest/request/multipart_with_file.rb:15:in `call'
from /Users/gregg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/faraday-0.8.8/lib/faraday/connection.rb:253:in `run_request'
from /Users/gregg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/faraday-0.8.8/lib/faraday/connection.rb:118:in `post'
from /Users/gregg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/twitter-5.1.1/lib/twitter/rest/client.rb:131:in `request'
from /Users/gregg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/twitter-5.1.1/lib/twitter/rest/client.rb:103:in `post'
from /Users/gregg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/twitter-5.1.1/lib/twitter/rest/api/utils.rb:123:in `object_from_response'
from /Users/gregg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/twitter-5.1.1/lib/twitter/rest/api/tweets.rb:125:in `update'
from drbronnersbot.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas of what settings I'm missing at dev.twitter.com? Or otherwise? Below is my code:

```
require 'twitter'

def pick_random_line
  chosen_line = nil
  File.foreach("label.txt").each_with_index do |line, number|
    chosen_line = line if rand < 1.0/(number+1)
  end
  return chosen_line.scan(/.{1,140}/)
end


client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key    = "my key"
  config.consumer_secret = "my secret"
  config.access_token    = "my access token"
  config.access_token_secret = "my access token secret"
end

puts pick_random_line
client.update(pick_random_line)
```

Comment: Show the code too, not just the error.

Comment: Actually got it, the update didn't like me passing that directly so i did the following:

    tweet = pick_random_line.join
    client.update(tweet)